# Need the filename of the Rnw when knitr runs in rStudio

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio-server

When working on a reproducible research project, I would like to know the name of the Rnw file that is being run to use as an R variable.

This would be analogous to inserting an MSExcel filename in a footer

I am using RStudio Server on Ubuntu.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following two idioms to fetch the directory and name of the current file in `knitr`:

```
knitr:::.knitEnv$input.dir
knitr:::knit_concord$get("infile")
```

This is independent of RStudio, the `knitr` package is entirely responsible for this. These are private functions and variables that can change at any time without notice, so if you need something reliable, you might want to [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/new).

Answer (score 9):

`knitr` now has a method for this: `current_input()`

https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/701