# Need the filename of the Rmd when knitr runs

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Recently I asked about having an r variable set to the name of an Rmd file when knitr runs.

[Need the filename of the Rnw when knitr runs in rStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957129/need-the-filename-of-the-rnw-when-knitr-runs-in-rstudio)

```
knitr:::.knitEnv$input.dir
knitr:::knit_concord$get("infile")
```

Is there a similar knitr::: object for the name of an Rmd file?

Comment: IMHO the type of the input file does not matter.

Comment: I believe `knitr:::knit_concord$get("infile")` is specific to Rnw latex files

Comment: No, it is not specific to Rnw files. It applies to all files that `knitr` supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search through the parent.frames until you find the frame referring to where the body of the function `knitr` is being evaluated (and thus the `input` argument is defined.

```
get(env = parent.frame(n = 8), 'input')
```

Works for me.

Note that I have not tested what happens if `input` is not a file name.....

Comment: I think that was my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

knitr::current_input() will return the name of the Rmd file